# Compilation error with generics wildcard methods

Tags: java, generics

I thought i was comfortable with generics until i faced this problem :

I have the following class:

```java
public class Item<T> {
    T item;

    public T getItem() {
        return item;
    }
}
```

and the following methods:

```java
public static void myFunction1(Map<?, String> map) {
    //some code
}

public static void myFunction2(Map<Item<?>, String> map) {
    //some code
}
```

And when i call myFunction1 and myFunction2:

```java
myFunction1(new HashMap<Item<String>, String>()); //compilation OK
myFunction2(new HashMap<Item<String>, String>()); //compilation error
```

I don't understand why when i call myFunction2 i get a compilition error, i read many articles and documentations about generics and i don't understand why.

Can somebody could explain why ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: Because `Item<String>` is a `?`. `Item<String>` is not an `Item<?>`. Generics are not covariant.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but if Item<String> is not an Item<?> why Item<?> item = new Item<String>(); is correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably meant

```
public static void myFunction2(Map<? extends Item<?>, String> map)
```

An `Item<String>` is not an `Item<?>`, but an `Item<String>` is a `? extends Item<?>`, or, more broadly, a `?`.

Look at [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html), there is a good hierarchy diagram at the end.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but when i look the diagram i understand that there is a relation between Item<?> and Item<String> (Item<?> item = new Item<String>(); is correct)

Comment: @valoo86 your parameter is a `Map`, not `Item`

Comment: Ok, it's due to generic covariance thank you very much